Reschedule Italy Visitor Visa Appointment
I have scheduled a visitor visa appointment with the Italian Consulate in Boston for August 15th on https://prenotami.esteri.it.
Can I reschedule the appointment to a prior date? I am not seeing that option without cancelling the current appointment first. As I don't see if earlier slots are available, I do not want to cancel the current appointment prematurely in the hope of getting an earlier appointment.
Has anyone been successful rescheduling an appointment to a prior date? Did you have to open a different account to view what appointments are available?

AFAIK you typically can’t book two appointment dates for the same passport number, and if you cancel an existing appointment you have to wait 24 hours for it to ‘clear’ from the system before you can book another date.
